# C# passing string between voids

Tags: c#, winforms

All i want to do is pass a string from one void to another.

```
private void getFilename2()
    {
        if (textBox2.TextLength.Equals("0"))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            string inputString = textBox2.Text.ToString();
            string last = inputString.Substring(inputString.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            string[] filename2 = last.Split('.');
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getFilename1();
        getFilename2();
string filez = filename2;
}
```

I know this doesn't work but I'm very unfamiliar with how to move strings around in voids.

Comment: Is there any reason why the getFilename2 method cannot return a string?

Comment: I think this is my favorite question ever!

Comment: You should name your textboxes.

Comment: sorry but you just made my day.

Comment: Easy! start a brand new thread, pass string You want to deliver to 2nd void, serialize it to binary, then - store it on Azure cloud. In 2nd void - use `Thread.Sleep(10000)` (or larger) to wait a bit and then - just retrieve it back from cloud. :)

Comment: @SLaks, he has, he's called it `textBox2` ... ;=)

Answer (score 8):

You should replace your `getFilename2` function with

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textBox2.Text)
```

Comment: Which returns a string you can use directly `string filez = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textBox2.Text);`

Comment: This may be good to clean up the code, but doesn't answer the fundamental question by the OP. Not down-voting, but not sure why this is being up-voted.

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet would be to use a class field/property, or a function that returns a value.

```
string filez = GetFilename2();

private string GetFilename2() {
{    
    if (textBox2.TextLength.Equals("0")) return "";

    string inputString = textBox2.Text.ToString();    
    string last = inputString.Substring(inputString.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);    
    return last.Split('.');    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the string by reference as a parameter to your functions

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName;
    getFilename1(ref string fileName);
}

private void getFilename1(ref string fileName)
{
    // Whatever you do with fileName here will be reflected in the other function
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually keeping the voids as requested. Although I agree he should just return the string.

Comment: I also agree that he should just return a string for this scenario, although I have encountered some weird coding problems that require us to get creative so figured I'd post this solution as an alternative :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with the name of your method: `getFilename2`.

- The prefix of "get" implies the method should have a return type
- A more appropriate name may be `SetFileName`

I'm assuming there is a `getFileName1` method that is retrieving the file name from `textBox1` and has the exact same code as `getFileName2`, but uses `textBox1` instead of `textBox2`.  This would be a good place to refactor your code and create a common method that can be reused:

```
private string GetFileName(string str) 
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return string.Empty;

  string last = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);    
  return last.Split('.');    
}
```

But, we can refactor again and just use a built-in .NET method:

```
private string GetFileName(string str) 
{
  return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str);
}
```

And now that there is a common method, we can re-use it as needed:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string filez = GetFileName(textBox2.Text);
}
```

Now we have a method of GetFileName(); all it is doing is calling a built-in .NET method of GetFileNameWithoutExtension(). So, instead of even having a method, we should just use the built-in .NET method for returning a file name:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string filez = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textBox2.Text);
}
```

Now, let's look at passing a string from one void to another. Typically, you'd want to do this with an internal field or property. Since I'm partial to properties, I'll use them as an example:

```
private string FileName1 {get; set;}
private string FileName2 {get; set;}

private void SetFileName1()
{
  FileName1 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textBox1.Text);
}
private void SetFileName2()
{
  FileName2 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textBox2.Text);
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SetFileName1();
  SetFileName2();

  string filez1 = FileName1;
  string filez2 = FileName2;
}
```

However, if you did not want to use internal fields or properties, you could set the values by ref as answered by [Rachel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502801/c-passing-string-between-voids/3502850#3502850)

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing strings around, ideally you should be *explicitly* passing them around.  IE: make your functions take and/or return the values they'll work with, especially if the return values aren't intended to be used by anything but the code that calls `getFilename2`.  If you can't do that, however, you can declare a `private string filename1 = null; public string[] filename2 = null` inside the class, but outside any of your methods.

If you go that route, make sure to remove any `string filename1` or `string[] filename2` from your methods, or you'll end up declaring a local variable with the same name (and never setting the instance variables).

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a class level variable. In that way it can be accessed by any function.